# how to use openvino in .net application?

Tags: .net, inference, openvino

I would like to know if it is possible to use openvino in a .net application?

I have converted a yolo network to a onnx network to use with ml.net. What I would like to do next is to implement openvino to see if it speeds up. So far I have converted my onnx model with openvino Model_optimizer but so far could not find any way to implement openvino in a .net app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up till this moment, there's no official support for OpenVINO integration with .NET application. Instead, the OpenVINO has its own Inference Engine application that supports both C++ and Python. You may refer [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Deep_Learning_Inference_Engine_DevGuide.html) for more info.

Performance-wise, since you mention speeding things up, you could try to use [OpenVINO Post-Training Optimization Tool](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/pot_README.html) to accelerate the inference of deep learning models.

Plus, ensure to [choose the right precision for Deep Learning model](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/should-i-choose-fp16-or-fp32-for-my-deep-learning-model.html) according to the hardware you are going to use for inferencing.

Comment: Thank you, it is my understanding that if i optimize it with the optimization tool I also have to do inference with its own inference engine.. is that correct?

Comment: @sharkyenergy yes, you need to use OV's InferenceEngine API. A very good python example is here https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/002-openvino-api/002-openvino-api.ipynb
The python API is aligned with C++ which means you need to do something very similar if you're planning to create a cpp application.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is onnx runtime where you can run your inference in c# and train the model in python and convert into onnx model (model.onnx)
link for reference: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/get-started/with-csharp.html